# In laravel phpunit testing, how to test a method that returns a class with parameters

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-9

```
public function download(Request $request): SampleClass
  {
    [$c, $p] = $this->_validateRequest($request);

    [, $r] = $this->_buildTempFileLoc($request);

    $contents = Storage::disk("someDir")->get($r);

    $rows = json_decode($contents, true);

    return new SampleClass(
      $payload["someVar"],
      $rows,
      $client->someProps,
      $request->someProps1 === "value",
    );
  }
```